# (Swipe Views) how to make Fragment objects dynamically for ViewPager at runtime?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentstatepageradapter

The idea: In my app, it has 15 lessons, each lesson containing 30 couplets a user can swipe through. And each fragment/couplet_page has inflated a layout that contains 3 text views. I'm using FragmentStatePagerAdapter.

I've learned that use switch case statements to create swipe views but the problem is, there are lots of fragments to be created and I know that there is a better solution for it that I don't know. I just wanna use one fragment and somehow change the text with setText method.

here's my one fragment object code

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class CoupletOneFragment extends Fragment {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.couplet_one, container, false);
    }
}
```

and here's the custom pager adapter

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;


public class MyFragmentAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public MyFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
       switch (position) {
           case 0:
               return new CoupletOneFragment();
           case 1:
               return new CoupletTwoFragment();
           case 2:
               return new CoupletThreeFragment();
           case 3:
               return new CoupletFourFragment();
           case 4:
               return new CoupletFiveFragment();
and so on...
           default:
               break;
       }
       return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {return 30;}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I'm gonna answer my own question here

Updated fragment object code

```
public class FragmentChild extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // INFLATE THE LAYOUT THAT EACH FRAGMENT OBJECT WILL HAVE, PUT IT IN A VIEW
     View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.couplets, container, false);

    // RECEIVE THE BUNDLE DATA SENT (ARGUMENTS)
    Bundle args = getArguments();

    // CREATE AN ARRAY LIST OF STRINGS THAT WILL HOLD TEXT
    ArrayList<String> someText = new ArrayList<>();
someText.add("one");
someText.add("two");
someText.add("three");
TextView txt = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
    txt.setText(someText.get(args.getInt("position")));
return root;
}
```

Updated custom pager adapter

```
class MyFragmentAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

 MyFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {super(fm);}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("position", position);

    Fragment fragment = new FragmentChild();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 3;
}
}
```

And finally host activity

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_chapter_one);

    // FIND THE VIEWPAGER AND SET THE CUSTOM ADAPTER TO IT TO PROVIDE CHILD PAGES
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        MyFragmentAdapter adapter = new MyFragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

It was easy peasy!

Answer (score 0):

Try this way, in your state pager adapter use loop- size is number of fragments:

```
ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        for (int i=0;i<size;i++){

            adapter.addFragment(CoupletFiveFragment.newInstance(i));
        }

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Adapter:

```
public  class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);

        }


    }
```

Now your Fragment:

```
public static CoupletFiveFragment newInstance(int j) {
        CoupletFiveFragment fragmentDemo = new CoupletFiveFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("GET_LIST", j);
        fragmentDemo.setArguments(args);
        return fragmentDemo;
    }
```

Get Value in Oncreate:

```
Int getINT=0;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getINT = getArguments().getInt("GET_LIST");

    }
```

Comment: Thanks man! I've few doubts here. first: in for-loop which object's size 'size' is representing? (ArrayList size)? second: Can I use FragmentStatePagerAdapter? Third: How do I put text in the Fragment and change it (Are this bundle, args and setArguments() are responsible for this) Last: this onCreate method is in the fragment extended class?

Comment: I know my questions must be annoying you but gotta ask, new to android. I hope you understand and answer those questions as well as you can. Thanks so far!

Comment: I tell you tommorow.

Comment: size is number of fragment's instance you want to show in viewpager. here in your case size is 4.

Comment: yes, you can use FragmentStatePagerAdapter. and you can pass text, whole arraylist, anything using Bundle